# Issue with Document Library

Tags: 2010, error, document, library

I have an issue with Document Library

- I am trying to upload one document and in the "processing" screen that comes before the new item form appears there was an arror (attached) and it would not move ahead to the form.
- However, even though I cancelled that page, when we searched for the document, it showed in the library, but with details of some random previous document.
- Then I changed the document and uploaded again. It uploaded, but again was added as a new version to the above mentioned file and the randomly picked details were still there.
- I manually deleted those details. This is not the first time this has happened. But there is no clear pattern of errors or any link about from where it is picking random details.
- This is causing a lot of confusion as wrong details get fetched, time wastage as documents don't get uploaded at times. Because wrong details are fetched and workflows run on them, wrong details are circulated on emails and emails are sent to wrong people.

Please help![image]

Comment: Have a look at what the real exception is in your ULS Logs.

Comment: and show a bit of code....

Comment: I assume there is no code, @SteveB. Based on the processing screen, I belive he is using the standard upload page... I'm right, @saumlim? Anyway, looking at the log to see if there are other error message related to the issue could help.

Comment: Also... Since you are saying that the document "was added as a new version" I was wondering - is the file that you are uploading a modified copy of a file that was downloaded from SharePoint? What metadata shows up with the old value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding out whether any details columns got corrupted and re-adding them again if they did. It could be because Microsoft is reporting the error wrong. [Here's](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2013/01/sharepoint-error-0x81020030-invalid.html) a post that someone wrote about how corrupt columns cause that error.